# How can I extract the list of urls obtained during a HTML page render in python?

Tags: python, http, http-headers

I want to be able to get the list of all URLs that a browser will do a GET request for when we try to open a page. For eg: if we try to open cnn.com, there are multiple URLs within the first HTTP response which the browser recursively requests for.

I'm not trying to render a page but I'm trying to obtain a list of all the urls that are requested when a page is rendered. Doing a simple scan of the http response content wouldn't be sufficient as there could potentially be images in the css which are downloaded. Is there anyway I can do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you'll have to render the page (not necessarily display it though) to be sure you're getting a complete list of all resources. I've used [`PyQT`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) and [`QtWebKit`](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit) in similar situations. Especially when you start counting resources included dynamically with javascript, trying to parse and load pages recursively with `BeautifulSoup` just isn't going to work.

[Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) is an excellent client to get you started with PyQT. Also, check out the [QWebView docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebview.html) and the [QNetworkAccessManager docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qnetworkaccessmanager.html).

Ghost.py returns a tuple of (page, resources) when opening a page:

```
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()
page, resources = ghost.open('http://my.web.page')
```

`resources` includes all of the resources loaded by the original URL as HttpResource objects. You can retrieve the URL for a loaded resource with `resource.url`.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I want. I'm implementing it right now. Will update the post with the results.

Comment: @user2188950 i will be interested in knowing your results

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to create a list of all known file extensions that you do NOT want, and then scan the content of the http response, checking with "if substring not in nono-list:"

The problem is all href's ending with TLDs, forwardslashes, url-delivered variables and so on, so i think it would be easier to check for stuff you know you dont want.