# Ghost.py return list of forms

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, ghost.py

Ive just installed [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) in order to scrape some site that require me to have javascript. Is there anyway to get an iterable list of forms on the current page much like the mechanize module would with `mechanize.Browser().forms()`? Or if not can I pass the page (after all the javascript stuff has loaded) to the mechanize library and let it fill out/submit the forms?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513699/how-can-i-extract-the-list-of-urls-obtained-during-a-html-page-render-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can do this for you if you don't mind a browser popping up on your screen.  It can run headless too, but that's trickier.  A simple solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp"
driver.get(url)
# get a list of the page's forms as Selenium WebElements
# (webdriver API ref: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html)
forms = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//form")
for i, form in enumerate(forms):
    print i, form.text

# the last form, index number 5, has input tags of type "text" and "submit" 
"""
<form name="input0" target="_blank" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
"
Username: "
<input type="text" name="user" size="20">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
"""

# get the input WebElements from this form WebElement
inputs = forms[5].find_elements_by_xpath(".//input")
# write text to the text input, then submit the form
inputs[0].send_keys('hihi frds!')
inputs[1].submit()
```

Comment: good post... but could I not use the PhantomJS driver instead of the Firefox webdriver to make this totally headless by only changing 1 line (driver = webdriver.PhantomJS).