# Extract the list of URLs obtained during a HTML page render in Java

Tags: java, html, http, url

I want to be able to get the list of all URLs that a browser will do a GET request for when we try to open a page. For example, if we try to open cnn.com, there are multiple URLs within the first HTTP response which the browser recursively requests for.

I'm not trying to render a page, but I'm trying to obtain a list of all the URLs that are requested when a page is rendered. Doing a simple scan of the HTTP response content wouldn't be sufficient, as there could potentially be images in the CSS which are downloaded. Is there any way I can do this in Java?

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513699/how-can-i-extract-the-list-of-urls-obtained-during-a-html-page-render-in-python), but I want to write this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Jsoup` library to extract all the links from a webpage, e.g.:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();
Elements links = document.select("a[href]");
for(Element link : links) {
    System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
}
```

[Here's](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/overview-summary.html) the documentation.

Comment: This code gives the list of all the links which are on the google.com page after page load. I want list of those URLs which URL refers in order to build the page, when the page is being loaded. This list includes URLs of css, js, png, etc. type of  files.

Comment: Do you want the list of links before the page is loaded?

Comment: Yeah I want the links when the page is getting loaded. Whatever the main URL refers like .js, .css or anything to build the web page.

Comment: This does exactly the same. It does't load the page, it parses it to a `Document` object.

Comment: The code you provided actually isn't giving any .js or .css or .png file's URL. Its just the list of links that we can see on screen not those which are used to build the Page.